# How to pick out specific parts of a text box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox

I am trying to pick out specific letters/numbers from a text box, because each means something. After that I am trying to display in a label what it means.

So if I have a number AB-123456, I need to first pick out AB something like:

```
If (textBox.Text.Substring(0,2) == "AB") {

//Display to a label

}
```

First off, this doesn't work and I also tried substring(0,1) but also was receiving errors when I used my clear button to clear the text box.

After that I still need to pull the rest of the numbers. The next one I need to pull and define is 123, then 4 by itself, 5 by itself, and six by itself.

How do I go about pulling each of these individually if substring isnt working?

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't really help us help you. What's the problem? I suspect you're getting an exception because you're asking for a range that's out of the dimensions of the string?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx would be a way to check a string for some value

Comment: @Luaan exactly, it says "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"

Comment: Are you doing anything else in addition to "if (textBox.Text.Substring(0,2) == "AB")"? Your error would only occur in the instance of your string being less than 2 characters.

Comment: Well, the solution is quite simple - check the length of the string before using `Substring`. As for accessing char by char, you can simply use the indexer (e.g. `textBox.Text[7]`). If the format is fixed, you could also use a `MaskedTextBox` for additional UI and validation - then you can only try to parse the ID when it's actually valid.

Comment: You could also use `textBox.Text.StartsWith("AB")` to check the first two characters. Use this if you don't want to have to check the Length of the text first. Also, you can include a StringComparison argument if you want to ignore case.

Comment: is this really your conditional check `If (textBox.Text.Substring(0,2) == "AB") {` ....the `If` should be all lower case ..also you need to show all code in your case because clearing out text should not cause an error unless you are checking the value of a textbox and it triggers the `OnChange` you need to add code that will check if the text is empty or not if so continue else do your SubString check if the text is always `AB-` some numbers then use `StartsWith` method

Comment: also if you have `AB-123456` and you check `textBox.Text.Substring(0,2)` you will get `AB` so it quite obvious that you have something else going on wrong in your code.. post the full event(s) so we can see what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input = textBox.Text;
// check the length before substring 
If (input.Length >= 2 && input.Substring(0,2) == "AB") {
    //Display to a label
}
```

or use regex:

```
string txt="AB-1234562323";
string re="AB-(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1

 Regex r = new Regex(re,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
 Match m = r.Match(txt);
 if (m.Success)// match found
 {
       // get the number 
       String number=m.Groups[1].ToString();  
 }
```

Comment: I used the first one and it worked correctly. But now I need to get the 123 pulled out from AB-123456. I re-declared the length to 6, but I dont understand how to use substring to only pull out "123"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (textBox.Text.StartsWith("AB"))
{
    //Display to a label
}
```

Use this if you don't want to have to check the Length of the text first. Also, you can include a StringComparison argument if you want to ignore case.